# JavaScript grab OAuth token from URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with an API that uses OAuth implicitly. It redirects to the URL http://exmaple.com/#token=084758yhroufgbk48y.

How do I grab this via JavaScript? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the hash part of the url using `window.location.hash`

To grab the token from the url use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    hash = window.location.hash.substr(1); //url of the current page
    arHash = hash.split('='); //this creates an array with key ([0] element) and value ([1] element)
    hash_value =  arHash[1]; //recieve value
</script>
```